# How to make a circle mesh with smooth coronas at different heights?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I am trying to make this effect with a mesh and geometry nodes.

[image]

As outlined in the picture, I would like:

1. The points of the circle to be at varying heights.
2. There to be a smooth curve between them.
3. To be able to animate the coronas heights.
4. For there to a similar effect in the centre.

I wonder if a torus might be the best primitive to start with here, and have played around with using a set position node, but can't achieve the detail I'd like.

[image]

[image]

Would love to hear any ways of achieving my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Using Bezier curves with [free handles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/write/set_handle_positions.html) to make sharp spikes connected by smooth curves, randomizing points around a circle.

[image: GN graph - Main]
[image: GN graph - Corona]

Input parameters are:
**Resolution:** Number of spikes.
**Radius:** Circle mean radius.
**Scale:** Factor controlling the spikes length.
**Angle:** Angle controlling the spikes sharpness. Positive values make outwards spikes; negative values make inward spikes.
**Noise:** Largest random displacement of spike heads.

Comment: That's a great setup. I would make just a few things different... first I used only one _Curve Handle Positions_ node but okay, for readability you could use two. Then the _Multiply_ with -1 before the _Vector Rotate_ is not necessary, therefore you can simply check _Invert_. And I made the _Noise_ a bit different. But anyway, great. Just for comparison my changes: [slightly adjusted nodetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFKtE.jpg)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: Thank you for the tip about the *Invert* check-box. I never paid attention to this property ! About the animation, if I get it right, you use the *Random Value* node *Seed* to set the "mean" pattern, then the *Noise Texture* node is providing a "Candle light" effect by modulating this pattern, instead of the brutal effect induced by animating the seed.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought the animated seed per frame was a bit too extremely flickering and since the seed only takes integers which give totally different results per step without any chance to slow it down, I took a different approach to get a more slowly wobbling effect. Another change I could have made would have been to add another input value as a factor for multiplying the _Seconds_ to change the speed of the wobble. And of course I could have used the _Frame_ output instead of _Seconds_.

Answer (score 2):

Try this geo nodes setup - rather simple really - 2 curve circles with their points set to fluctuate on the Z axis based on the W value of the 4D Noise textures. The Set Spline Type and Set handle type make sure the curves are smooth:

[image: Curves]

The Scene time connected to the W of the Noise Textures animates it.

[image: Curve]

NOTE - Sorry, I just saw you want the circle to deform in the X and Y axis as well - no bother, just connect the X and Y of the CombineXYZ nodes to the noise textures as well.